# Два типа подсветки синтаксиса для HTML в Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, синтаксис, sublime-text

В Sublime Text 3 почему то два типа подсветки синтаксиса: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcxoM.png.

Плагины:

- Emmet
- Plugin Control
- SublimeLinter
- SublimeLinter-php
- SublimeCodeIntel
- SFTP
- PyV8

Если все плагины включить, получается так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyqTe.png.

Система Windows 8.1 x86.
Как исправить?

Comment: Так это вполне штатная ситуация. Просто одна из подсветок дополняет другую, а не заменяет - потому и выбраны одновременно обе.

Comment: @shatal, молодец, только модераторы тут не при чем, там несколько иные задачи. Голосовать за закрытие можно уже при рейтинге от 500+, а ставить минусы вообще при 150. Инструменты модератора начинают выдаваться при рейтинге от 2000+ и выше. Для подобных вещей существует [мета](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/) на которой уже ведутся обсуждения этих вопросов и там можно привлечь внимание администраторов.